# AWS S3 Bucket Policy Access Denied Tag Condition EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I've read up and down the documentation, and cannot seem to download files from s3 bucket with bucket policy using wget from instance. I can however download using the s3 cp commands.

Ive tried most if not all global conditions but none seem to allow the wget download.
Examples are aws:PrincipalTag, aws:ResourceTag, aws:PrincipalArn for instance profile role attached to instance.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html

```
{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:List*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-config-folder/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-config-folder"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:ResourceTag/ROLE":"TEST"
            },
            "Bool": {
                "aws:SecureTransport": "true"
            }
        }
    },

"Condition": {
            "ArnLike": {
                "aws:PrincipalArn": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789456:role/instance-role-*",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789456:role/instance-profile-*",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789456:role/service-role-*",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789456:role/instance-role-blue-dev-env",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789456:instance-profile/instance-profile-dev",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789456:role/instance-role-dev",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789456:role/instance-profile-*"
                ]
            }
        }
    },


"Condition": {
            "ArnLike": {
                "ec2:SourceInstanceARN": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789456:role/instance-role-*",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789456:role/instance-profile-*",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789456:role/service-role-*",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789456:role/instance-role-blue-dev-env",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789456:instance-profile/instance-profile-dev",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789456:role/instance-role-dev",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789456:role/instance-profile-*"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/taskdef-envfiles.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_image

```
"command": [],
  "linuxParameters": null,
  "cpu": 10,
  "environment": [
    {
      "name": "APP_CONFIG_URL",
      "value": "https://my-config-folder.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/qa/app/testapp/appconfig.properties"
    },
    {
      "name": "DIRECT_MEMORY_SIZE",
      "value": "512m"
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have all these conditions if bucket is supposed to be public?

Comment: I dont have all of these conditions, These are the condition combinations I have tried to date. The Public bucket requirement is for wget requests , but this is needed internally only. Ive also tried the IP option which works but this is static and need something dynamic as Instances will be destroyed

Answer (score 2):

When you use the AWS CLI, the API calls are signed using the credentials stored in your configuration file (or assigned to the EC2 instance via an IAM Role).

However, when you use `wget`, it does not know your identity, so the request will be denied.

Therefore, it is preferable to use the AWS CLI to download objects, or a program that uses an AWS SDK.

If you really do want to access objects via `wget`, you can generate [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which append identity information and a hashed signature to grant access to private objects.

Comment: Thank you for this , as always John very helpful , ill research this further

Comment: Can I still reference the https in config file such as ECS like below ? or would it not know identity similar to the wget call?  


Config Reference in Task Definition within ECS



"command": [],
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 10,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "APP_CONFIG_URL",
          "value": "https://my-config-folder.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/qa/app/testapp/appconfig.properties"
        },
        {
          "name": "DIRECT_MEMORY_SIZE",
          "value": "512m"
        }

Comment: What will be consuming that information? Can you point us to some documentation?

Comment: Hope this assists , https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/taskdef-envfiles.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_image


"command": [],
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 10,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "APP_CONFIG_URL",
          "value": "https://my-config-folder.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/qa/app/testapp/appconfig.properties"
        },
        {
          "name": "DIRECT_MEMORY_SIZE",
          "value": "512m"
        }

Comment: I have added to main question on end for better format

Comment: That documentation does not refer to `APP_CONFIG_URL`, so I have no idea how that value would be used.

Comment: sorry for the confusion john , the APP_CONFIG_URL is the variable name under the environment in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/taskdef-envfiles.html the value would be the https link to the s3 bucket where the container would pull in a config file

Comment: I still cannot see a reference to `APP_CONFIG_URL` in that documentation.